# myslqli_query() wont INSERT data into my database

Tags: php

I'm having problems with `mysqli_query`. I have methods set up in a singleton database class call `connect()` and `querydb()`, `querydb` takes a `$query` parameter which I'm sure is fine as I used the query to add data to my table in phpMyAdmin. here is my PHP method for when I attempt to add data to the table in my register.php class.

```
public function register() {

   $databaseinst = database:: getinstance();
   $conn =   $databaseinst->connect();

   $query = "INSERT INTO  Customer (email_address,firstname,lastname,address_line_1,address_line_2,city,postcode,country,password) VALUES ('$this->email','$this->firstname','$this->secondname','$this->address1','$this->address2','$this->city','$this->postcode','$this->country','$this->password1')";

   $numrows = $databaseinst->querydb($query);

       if ( false===$numrows ) {
    $this->errors[]= mysqli_error($conn);
    }

       if ($numrows < 1) {
            $this->errors[] = "could not process query";
        }
        if($conn == 0)
        {
        $this->errors[] = "couldnt connect";
        }
        if($conn == 1)
        {
        $this->errors[] = " connected";
        }
    }

    public function showerrors() {
        echo "<h3> ERRORS!!</h3>";
        echo "<p>" . var_dump($this->errors) . "</p>";
        foreach ($this->errors as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value . "</br>";
        }
    }
```

The second method is just how I print out the errors when they occur.
Next are the methods from my database singleton class which returns an instance fine I think the issue is with the `mysqli_query()` method call in my `querydb()` method just can figure out what it is I keep getting a "could not process query" reply. Anyway here is the singleton class I used which is pretty much an edited version of one I found online.

```
<?php

class database {

private static $instance;
private $dbcon;
private $result;
private $numrows;


private function __construct()
{

}

  static function getinstance()
{
    if(!self::$instance)
    {
     self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;

 }

public function connect()
{
    $this->dbcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','********','****');
  if (!$this->dbcon)
  {
  return 0;
  }
  else
  {
  return 1;
  }

}

 public function querydb($query)
{

mysqli_select_db($this->dbcon,'theislan_testdatabase');

$this->result = mysqli_query($this->dbcon,$query);
$this->numrows = $this->result->num_rows;

   if ($this->numrows < 1)
   {
      return 0;

   }
  else 
    {
        return 1;
    }
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: try `echo`ing `$query`, make sure its a valid query.

Comment: please, stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions and learn how to work with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Oh .. and there are [some things you should know about singletons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Comment: the query is okay i used it in myphpadmin where you can just run a query and it worked

Comment: hey man im pretty new to this and im trying to teach myself for a project that i have to have done in two weeks, im not enjoying the experience at the moment because im under pressure

Comment: just to try and get something up and running is my goal at this stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the user you use to connect to MySQL allowed to INSERT? In other words, is it MySQL permission that cause the problem, not PHP? Try testing with root user to establish whether that's the case (or check permissions in PHPMyAdmin).

Comment: cant figure out how exactly to do this

Comment: In phpMyAdmin you should be able to see a link called 'privileges'. Click on that and then click to edit the user you use to connect to the DB. Assuming the user does not have global privileges, check under 'Database-specific privileges' and that it says the user has INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE privileges or ALL.

Comment: this is what i see when i go into phpmyadmin     Databases
    SQL
    Status
    Processes
    Export
    Import
    Variables
    Charsets
    Engines
    Synchronize
    Settings.

Comment: no privileges. all i really want to do is create a user when he submits details like email, password ,address and add them to the database.

Comment: Ok you are probably have a shared setup and don't have permission to set permissions? Perhaps get your server admin to check your privileges ...

Comment: thanks again fred2, im pretty sure when i set up the user with the database i was sent to a screen with checkboxes that i had to click on to allow certain queries, if this is what you are talking about? i set them all to on so i could perform any type of query.!

Comment: do you get any error other than 'could not process query'? ie - a real mysql error?

Comment: well the query bypasses the if ( false===$numrows ) {
   $this->errors[]= mysqli_error($conn);
  }

Comment: but it should return false on failure!? this is very strange!

Comment: damn im getting mixed up here. ive just been at it too long! ill go at it again in the morning! thanks again Fred

Comment: ah yes! i fixed it, i should of just been returning the connection instead of 1 or 0. when im tired  i start doing stupid stuff! now i can sleep soundly!